# Trouble with Pandas series. Trying to strip or replace using Regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Within a pandas dataframe (df) I have a series (df['reports']) which I want to clean up.

Each string in the series has some junk I want to delete from it, for example:
    df['reports'][10]

```
[{'url': 'http://208.xx.xx.19/uploads/media/default/0001/02/e633f1d80a61d17e041ffd994355ccb618a024e5.pdf'}]
```

What I want to delete from this is: (in double quotes)

"[{'url': '" from the left

and

"'}]" from the right

I have already tried:

```
df['reports'].str.lstrip('url') #this didn't work, even just to remove the 'url' part
df['reports'].replace({'[{}]'}regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\[\{\'\w{3}',value=r'
df['reports'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\[\{\'url\'',value=r'')
df['reports'] = df['reports'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('\[{\'url\': \'').rstrip('\'}]\''))
```

Now I am trying:

```
df['reports'].replace({'\[\{\'url\'':' '},regex=True,inplace=True)
```

I expect at least one of these solutions to be either stripping out the characters that I don't want and giving me something like
"http://208.xx.xx.19/uploads/media/default/0001/02/e633f1d80a61d17e041ffd994355ccb618a024e5.pdf" for every "cell" in the series.

EDIT: Making a mock dataseries here as an example of what the desired output might look like:

```
In: df['reports']

Out:
*reports*
http://208.xx.xx.19/uploads/media/default/0001/02/e633f1.pdf
http://208.xx.xx.19/uploads/media/default/0001/02/exyz2.pdf
http://208.xx.xx.19/uploads/media/default/0001/02/e633342.pdf
http://208.xx.xx.19/uploads/media/default/0001/02/ashj39.pdf
http://208.xx.xx.19/uploads/media/default/0001/02/asdji34q2.pdf
Name: reports, Length: 155, dtype: object
```

Comment: in your example, can you show what you want the expected output to be? I see you typed it out, but visual learners (like myself) seeing is worth 1000 words

Comment: @MattR sure if you show me how. Since I have not achieved the desired output I have nothing to screenshot. The desired output would be that series of the dataframe with all the junk characters stripped off in each cell.

Comment: Can you physically show us your desired output? if we don't know what the end product should look like, how will we know how to help you?

Comment: @MattR Sorry I am not sure how to answer your query. I have asked you *how* I can show you and you have not told me. I can make a mock data series in the question above in the hopes that it satisfies your need for a "physical" demonstration of the desired output.

Comment: The mock data is exactly what we will need :)

Comment: It turns out the '{' and the '[' were not just characters. It was a dictionary within a list within the data "cell" in the series. I don't know why it's like that, but there you go. It seems I don't need the regex or strip or anything. Sorry I was confused

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
df['reports'].str.replace("^\[{'url': ","").str.replace("}\]$","")
```

The first "str.replace" looks for a pattern "[{'url': " at the beginning, and the second for "}]" at the end.

EDIT: since the series entries are actually a list of dictionary, the solution was:

```
df['reports'].apply(lambda x:x[0]['url'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work. 
If I use the code as is df['reports'].str.replace("^\[{'url': ","").str.replace("}\]$","") 
then I get:
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
However, if I make it two lines, like:
df['reports'].str.replace("^\[{'url': ","")
df['reports'].str.replace("}\]$","")

I get a series of NaN printed. (I forgot to mention in my question that I get this series of NaN from some of the approaches I took). Do you know why I am getting these problems?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I misunderstood what your dataframe was.
Then would that work:
df['reports'].apply(lambda x:x[0]['url'])? It seems your series is a list of dictionnaries.

Comment: I have just discovered this myself too!
df['reports'][10][0]['url'] gives me a string.

So actually each "cell" in the series contains a list which contains a dictionary. I don't know why. But I am step closer to solving this.  THANKS for your help